# Mock a JSON request parameter using Quarkus and RestAssured

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, rest-assured, quarkus

Using Quarkus, I have the following API.

```java
@RequestScoped
@Path("/api/v1")
public class MyApi {

    @POST
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(Entity entityToCreate) {
        if (entityToCreate.isValid()) {
            // create the entity in my app...
            return Response.ok().build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }
}
```

My `Entity` class looks like this

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Entity {

    private final String property1;
    private final String property2;
    // ...

    @JsonCreator
    public Entity(@JsonProperty("property1") String property1,
                  @JsonProperty("property2") String property2,
                  // ...
    ){
        this.property1 = property1;
        this.property2 = property2;
        // ...
    }

    // getters for every property...

    public boolean isValid() {
        // check if the entity is valid, then return true or false
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve, in my unit tests, is the following:

```java
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@QuarkusTest
public class MyApiTest {
    
    private final Entity entityMock = mock(Entity.class);
    
    @Test
    public void shouldCreateEntityWhenValid(){
        when(entityMock.isValid()).thenReturn(true);

        given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(entityMock)
        .when()
            .post("/api/v1")
        .then()
            .statusCode(200);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotCreateEntityWhenInvalid(){
        when(entityMock.isValid()).thenReturn(false);

        given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(entityMock)
        .when()
            .post("/api/v1")
        .then()
            .statusCode(400);
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm stuck with the following error, because Jackson tries to deserialize the mock.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.mockito.internal.invocation.mockref.MockWeakReference and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: blah blah blah... )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mixing several test techniques, to validate both the JSON mapping and the method behaviour.

```java
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@QuarkusTest
public class MyApiTest {
    
    private final Entity entityMock = mock(Entity.class);
    private final Entity validEntity = // [...] instantiate a valid entity here
    
    private MyApi api;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        myApi = new MyApi();
    }    

    // this test validates both the JSON parsing and the valid entity case
    @Test
    public void shouldCreateEntityWhenValid(){ 
        given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(validEntity)
        .when()
            .post("/api/v1")
        .then()
            .statusCode(200);
    }
    
    // this test validates the invalid entity case
    @Test
    public void shouldNotCreateEntityWhenInvalid(){
        when(entityMock.isValid()).thenReturn(false);

        Response response = myApi.create(entityMock);

        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(400);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first test doesn't do what you think it does. Read my explanation again.

Comment: Thanks for your vigilance. It was a wrong copy/paste. I instantiate a real valid entity in the first test case.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a real instance of your entity and let the validation happen.

Rest Assured is going to post an actual HTTP request in the test, so it serializes your mock as JSON. When the implementation handles the HTTP request, the request body is then deserialized into an entity. This entity is instantiated internally, so it’s not the same instance as created in the test.

Comment: I don't want to instantiate a real entity. The conditions leading to a valid or invalid object is not the concern of `MyApi` class, or its test class. I don't want to have to choose a specific valid or invalid configuration of the entity.

Comment: The deserialization is done by the framework so you don't really have an option. If you want to separate the validation concern you cannot test it with an integration test like this.

Comment: You can still test the validation separately by writing a unit test for the entity. But the handling of the validation in the controller requires something to actually trigger the validation.

Comment: I tested the validation separately. In the controller, I may end up mixing RestAssured tests and more simple JUnit tests in which I will call the controller method myself...

Comment: If you really want to separate the validation concern I'd suggest throwing a ConstraintViolationException or using the Java validators. That way you only need one exception handler and can forget about handling the validation status manually in each controller method.